# How to create cummulative sum in dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas

How to create cumulative sum (new_supply)in dataframe python from demand column
from table

```
item   Date       supply  demand
A     2018-01-01  -       10
A     2018-01-02  -       15
A     2018-01-03  100     30
A     2018-01-04  -       10
A     2018-01-05  -       40
A     2018-01-06  50      50
A     2018-01-07  -       10
B     2018-01-01  -       20
B     2018-01-02  -       30
B     2018-01-03  20      60
B     2018-01-04  -       20
B     2018-01-05  100     10
B     2018-01-06  -       20
B     2018-01-07  -       30
```

New Desired table from the above table

```
item   Date       supply  demand  new_supply
A     2018-01-01  -       10      -
A     2018-01-02  -       15      -
A     2018-01-03  100     30      55
A     2018-01-04  -       10      -
A     2018-01-05  -       40      -
A     2018-01-06  50      50      100
A     2018-01-07  -       10      -
B     2018-01-01  -       20      -
B     2018-01-02  -       30      -
B     2018-01-03  20      60      110
B     2018-01-04  -       20      -
B     2018-01-05  100     10      140
B     2018-01-06  -       20      -
B     2018-01-07  -       30      -
```

Comment: Is output correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) for set new values only for numeric ones by column `supply`:

```
m = df['supply'].str.isnumeric()
g = m.iloc[::-1].cumsum()

df['new'] = np.where(m, df.groupby(['item',g])['demand'].cumsum(), '-')
print (df)
   item        Date supply  demand  new
0     A  2018-01-01      -      10    -
1     A  2018-01-02      -      15    -
2     A  2018-01-03    100      30   55
3     A  2018-01-04      -      10    -
4     A  2018-01-05      -      40    -
5     A  2018-01-06     50      50  100
6     A  2018-01-07      -      10    -
7     B  2018-01-01      -      20    -
8     B  2018-01-02      -      30    -
9     B  2018-01-03     20      60  110
10    B  2018-01-04      -      20    -
11    B  2018-01-05    100      10   30
12    B  2018-01-06      -      20    -
13    B  2018-01-07      -      30    -
```

Or:

```
m = df['supply'].str.isnumeric()

df['new'] = np.where(m, df.groupby('item')['demand'].cumsum(), '-')
print (df)
   item        Date supply  demand  new
0     A  2018-01-01      -      10    -
1     A  2018-01-02      -      15    -
2     A  2018-01-03    100      30   55
3     A  2018-01-04      -      10    -
4     A  2018-01-05      -      40    -
5     A  2018-01-06     50      50  155
6     A  2018-01-07      -      10    -
7     B  2018-01-01      -      20    -
8     B  2018-01-02      -      30    -
9     B  2018-01-03     20      60  110
10    B  2018-01-04      -      20    -
11    B  2018-01-05    100      10  140
12    B  2018-01-06      -      20    -
13    B  2018-01-07      -      30    -
```

If need all values:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('item')['demand'].cumsum()
print (df)
   item        Date supply  demand  new
0     A  2018-01-01      -      10   10
1     A  2018-01-02      -      15   25
2     A  2018-01-03    100      30   55
3     A  2018-01-04      -      10   65
4     A  2018-01-05      -      40  105
5     A  2018-01-06     50      50  155
6     A  2018-01-07      -      10  165
7     B  2018-01-01      -      20   20
8     B  2018-01-02      -      30   50
9     B  2018-01-03     20      60  110
10    B  2018-01-04      -      20  130
11    B  2018-01-05    100      10  140
12    B  2018-01-06      -      20  160
13    B  2018-01-07      -      30  190
```

Comment: As it appears, I think the OP wants the cumsum to be resetted after a new supply is issued, right? I was about to write an answer, but I searched first and found that [you have already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32891081/2099607) :)) The only difference is that a groupby is needed here.

Comment: @today - yes, it should working nice at least 0 value in `supply`... But still not 100% sure what OP need :(

Comment: Thanks brother, can answer please  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140438/how-to-create-cummulative-sum-in-dataframe-python-part2

Answer (score 0):

Simply as:

```
df['new_supply'] = df.demand.cumsum()
```

Precisely above should work, when we are looking for cumulative sum of a column..
Just simulating your DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   item        Date supply  demand
0     A  2018-01-01      -      10
1     A  2018-01-02      -      15
2     A  2018-01-03    100      30
3     A  2018-01-04      -      10
4     A  2018-01-05      -      40
5     A  2018-01-06     50      50
6     A  2018-01-07      -      10
7     B  2018-01-01      -      20
8     B  2018-01-02      -      30
9     B  2018-01-03     20      60
10    B  2018-01-04      -      20
11    B  2018-01-05    100      10
12    B  2018-01-06      -      23
13    B  2018-01-07      -      30
```

So, When we do `df.<particulat_col>.cumsum()` it will produce cumsun of that, in our case as follows with a new desired column along:

```
>>> df
   item        Date supply  demand  new_supply
0     A  2018-01-01      -      10          10
1     A  2018-01-02      -      15          25
2     A  2018-01-03    100      30          55
3     A  2018-01-04      -      10          65
4     A  2018-01-05      -      40         105
5     A  2018-01-06     50      50         155
6     A  2018-01-07      -      10         165
7     B  2018-01-01      -      20         185
8     B  2018-01-02      -      30         215
9     B  2018-01-03     20      60         275
10    B  2018-01-04      -      20         295
11    B  2018-01-05    100      10         305
12    B  2018-01-06      -      23         328
13    B  2018-01-07      -      30         358
```

If indeed we are looking for a aggregative or cumulative sum of two items , then it should be go along with `groupby` as follows:

```
>>> df['new_supply'] = df.groupby('item')['demand'].cumsum()

>>> df
   item        Date supply  demand  new_supply
0     A  2018-01-01      -      10          10
1     A  2018-01-02      -      15          25
2     A  2018-01-03    100      30          55
3     A  2018-01-04      -      10          65
4     A  2018-01-05      -      40         105
5     A  2018-01-06     50      50         155
6     A  2018-01-07      -      10         165
7     B  2018-01-01      -      20          20
8     B  2018-01-02      -      30          50
9     B  2018-01-03     20      60         110
10    B  2018-01-04      -      20         130
11    B  2018-01-05    100      10         140
12    B  2018-01-06      -      23         163
13    B  2018-01-07      -      30         193
```

**Note:**  *In case you need the output you desired then you have to modify your question with logic you are filtering the dataset indeed!*

Comment: hmmm, can you add output? I think it is different like OP need.

Comment: @jezrael, i do have Dataframe  to test , i need to reproduce one :-)