Calculating an ongoing win streak in a dataframe
I have a set of data for sport matches which is in a form like this:
winner = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B']
loser =  ['B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']
P1 =     ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
P2 =     ['B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
P1_win = [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({'winner': winner, 'loser': loser, 'P1':P1, 'P2':P2, 'P1_win':P1_win})
df


I want to calculate the ongoing win streaks for P1 and for P2. However, when I do this the streak doesn't reset when P_win == 0.
The code I am using to calculate the streaks is:
condition = df.P1_win.eq(0)
df['Reset'] = condition.groupby(df.P1_win).cumsum() #reset need to be 0. If P_win == 0, reset the line
df['P1_win_Streak'] = df.P1_win.mask(condition, 0).groupby([df.winner, df.Reset]).cumsum()

What is occurring is that whenever a streak ends, 0 is successfully input into the streak column, but the streak then picks up from its previous value, as in the image:

In my actual data set, it ends up like this:


the problem is that you are grouping by which doesn't take into account the spatial separation of data (its just going to group everything with similar criteria) which you are grouping together (and why you see the count increasing).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890124/pandas-dataframe-running-sum-with-reset with this reset needs to just be the inverse of P1_win

This might be what you want:
# Create a variable to indicate consecutive groups
groups = (df['P1_win'] != df['P1_win'].shift(1)).cumsum()

# Reset the count when encountering a zero value
df['count'] = df.groupby(groups)['P1_win'].cumsum()

This results in:


It seems difficult to do this vectorized, but this might work for smaller (<1 million row) dfs (you could also convert to numpy with df.to_numpy before iterating to make it much faster):
def calc_streaks(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    player_streaks = {}
    p1_streak = []
    p2_streak = []

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        player_streaks[row['loser']] = 0
        player_streaks[row['winner']] = player_streaks.get(row['winner'], 0) + 1

        p1_streak.append(player_streaks[row['P1']])
        p2_streak.append(player_streaks[row['P2']])

    df['P1_streak'] = p1_streak
    df['P2_streak'] = p2_streak
    return df

Output:
  winner loser P1 P2  P1_win  P1_streak  P2_streak
0      A     B  A  B       1          1          0
1      A     C  A  C       1          2          0
2      B     A  A  B       0          0          1
3      C     A  A  C       0          0          1
4      A     B  A  B       1          1          0
5      C     A  A  C       0          0          2
6      C     B  B  C       0          0          3
7      B     C  B  C       0          1          0


Thanks everyone for your help.
I figured it out in the end.
My code worked when there was only one player per row. So I split the dataframe into two based on winner and loser, renamed the columns to 'player', concatenated them, ran the code, then split the frame back out and remerged it.
Not very elegant, and quite expensive, but it gets the job done.
With my working code of tennis players:
#Calculateing win and lose streaks
streak1 = Richtennis[['match_id', 'tourney_date', 'winner_name']]
streak1.rename(columns={'winner_name':'player'}, inplace=True)
streak1['win'] =1
streak1['lose'] =0
streak1['tag'] = 'W'
streak2 = Richtennis[['match_id', 'tourney_date', 'loser_name']]
streak2.rename(columns={'loser_name':'player'}, inplace=True)
streak2['win'] =0
streak2['lose'] =1
streak2['tag'] = 'L'
streak = pd.concat([streak1, streak2], axis=0)
streak.sort_values(by='match_id', ascending=True, inplace=True)

condition = streak.win.eq(0)
conditionl = streak.lose.eq(0)
streak['Reset'] = condition.groupby(streak.player).cumsum()
streak['Resetl'] = conditionl.groupby(streak.player).cumsum()
streak['Win_ Streak'] = streak.win.mask(condition, 0).groupby([streak.player, streak.Reset]).cumsum()
streak['Lose_ Streak'] = streak.lose.mask(conditionl, 0).groupby([streak.player, streak.Resetl]).cumsum()

streak.drop(columns=['Reset', 'Resetl'], inplace=True)

#split on match _id, then match back to winner and loser _name
#create unique list of names
UniqueNames = streak.tag.unique()

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame() for elem in UniqueNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = streak[:][streak.tag == key]
    
dfWs = DataFrameDict['W']
dfLs = DataFrameDict['L']

dfWs.drop(columns = ['tag', 'win', 'lose', 'Lose_ Streak'], inplace=True)
dfLs.drop(columns = ['tag', 'win', 'lose', 'Win_ Streak'], inplace=True)

#mergbe back to Richtennis, then cast P1 and P2 streaks. 
Richtennis = pd.merge(Richtennis, dfWs, on='match_id', how = 'outer')
Richtennis.drop(columns = ['player', 'tourney_date_y'], inplace=True)
Richtennis = pd.merge(Richtennis, dfLs, on='match_id', how = 'outer')
Richtennis.drop(columns = ['player', 'tourney_date_x'], inplace=True)

#making win and lose streaks for players
Richtennis['P1_win_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P1'] == Richtennis['winner_name'], Richtennis['Win_ Streak'], 0)
Richtennis['P1_win_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P1'] == Richtennis['loser_name'], 0, Richtennis['Win_ Streak'])

Richtennis['P2_win_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P2'] == Richtennis['winner_name'], Richtennis['Win_ Streak'], 0)
Richtennis['P2_win_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P2'] == Richtennis['loser_name'], 0, Richtennis['Win_ Streak'])

Richtennis['P1_lose_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P1'] == Richtennis['loser_name'], Richtennis['Lose_ Streak'], 0)
Richtennis['P1_lose_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P1'] == Richtennis['winner_name'], 0, Richtennis['Lose_ Streak'])

Richtennis['P2_lose_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P2'] == Richtennis['loser_name'], Richtennis['Lose_ Streak'], 0)
Richtennis['P2_lose_streak'] = np.where(Richtennis['P2'] == Richtennis['winner_name'], 0, Richtennis['Lose_ Streak'])
Richtennis.drop(columns = ['Lose_ Streak', 'Win_ Streak'], inplace=True)

